# problems with ASA 8.4 Nat Rules for a Web Server

Tags: cisco-asa

Having problems with the NAT RULES and Access Rules changes on my ASA5505.
Want to straight replace a 5505 with a newer 5505 and unfortunately this means dealing with old version 7.2 and the newer 8.4 configurations.

my old NAT RULE:

```
static (inside,outside) WebOutside WebInside netmask 255.255.255.255
```

and an Access Rule of:

```
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any host WebOutside eq www
```

these dont work in 8.4 I understand there are some changed but I can find little information that makes any sense on how to configure these.

Any pointers welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NAT syntax has changed in 8.3 and up.

Define the NAT in the host object:

```
object network WebInside
 ! Inside address:
 host 192.0.2.1
 ! Outside address:
 nat (inside,outside) static 198.51.100.1
```

And your access list needs to change to use the host's post-NAT address.

```
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any host WebInside eq www
```

It may be simpler for you to upgrade the code on the old 5505 in order to get the configuration converted before moving to the new device.

Comment: This is a very good explanation that I could not find anywhere else, thank you very much.